# Blazor Server WebSocket connection failed: There was an error with the transport

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a problem in a `blazor server` application with **websockets**.

Using the application locally I have no problems, but when I load it on the hosting server I get these errors from the browser.

The application itself works correctly but occasionally some users get the message "Attempting to reconnect to the server".

[image: websocket error]

This is my `Startup.cs`

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ******
        // BLAZOR COOKIE Auth Code (begin)
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options => options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1));

        // BLAZOR COOKIE Auth Code (end)
        // ******

        services.AddMudServices();

        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
       
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();


        // ******
        // BLAZOR COOKIE Auth Code (begin)
        // HttpContextAccessor
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddScoped<HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddHttpClient();
        services.AddScoped<HttpClient>();
        // BLAZOR COOKIE Auth Code (end)
        // ******
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        // ******
        // BLAZOR COOKIE Auth Code (begin)
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        // BLAZOR COOKIE Auth Code (end)
        // ******

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
}
```

What could be the problem ?

Comment: If it's contextual, it's likely a problem with your server configuration, not your app. Can you provide more details about that?

Comment: If you're hosting it as a web app in Azure, make sure that on the web app's configuration, you've enabled the 'Use Websockets' options. Otherwise, the whole thing comes crashing down. - been there.

Comment: @Dennis1679 I am asking my host about the websockets settings because unfortunately I have very little control over the server.

Comment: @ConnorLow My hoster said websockets are active. What else could it be ?

Comment: Does your provider expose any debugging tools? Can you access any server logs?

Comment: @ConnorLow I asked but they don't give me access to any tools and logs. Is there anything i can ask the hoster to check?

Comment: Who are you hosting with?

Comment: @ConnorLow register.it, is an Italian hosting. The only thing I have is access to my domain's FTP. The server is virtual or otherwise a shared machine.

Comment: Have you published the app as a stand-alone runtime?

Comment: I now think it's a deployment/configuration error rather than a coding error. Try your app on Heroku or Firebase. Heroku should support blazor and it's free. Read how to do it [here](https://nightbaker.github.io/blazor/heroku/webassembly/dotnet/2019/12/12/heroku-blazor/) and [here](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack).

Comment: Note that Heroku [does not officially support .net technologies](https://help.heroku.com/PAT3YEDU/does-heroku-support-net-applications).

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error. I did not have ARR Affinity turned on the Azure App Service.

Turning it on fixed the issue.

See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/publish-to-azure-web-app?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-the-app-in-azure-app-service

Answer (score 0):

As I was just facing the same issue, maybe one additional note:
I had the WebApp created manually in the Azure portal (not via the VS deployment) and therefor had no SignalR service connected at all.

This was working without websockets, but when trying to switch websockets "ON", the app wouldn't load anymore.

Now it works with SignalR Service added under "Service Connector" section of the web app.